# Passing string to a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

The code given below reads file contents to buffer, and then does something with it.

```
char *getData(){
    char *buf = (char*) malloc(100);
    //write file contents to buf
    return buf;
}

char *bar(char *buf){
    //do something with buf
    return buf;
}

int main(void){
    char *result;

    result = bar(getData());

    return 0;
}
```

The `return buf;` at line 9 works fine - it returns the whole string. The question is how can I access individual characters in buf in function bar?

Comment: line 8: `    //do something with buf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to access the individual characters, you can do it as you'd do with any string in any other place: `buf[index]` (for pointers `ptr[index]` is exactly the same as `*(ptr+index)`).

By the way, in that code there's a `malloc` but not its corresponding `free` - you're leaking memory. In such a small program the problem is not evident (the application is terminated immediately, so all the still non-deallocated memory is automatically reclaimed by the OS), but in larger programs the problem can become serious.

Comment: and rather counter-intuitively index[ptr] is the same as *(index+ptr), which consequently does the same thing too!

Comment: @awoodland: yes, it's a weird-but-logical behavior that periodically is recalled here on SO. I wasn't quoting it to avoid confusing more the OP. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can have indexing.

```
if (buf != NULL) {
    int i = 0;
    while (buf[i] != '\0') {
        // Do Processing
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As char * is a array of string, you should use indexer buf[index] with it...

Answer (score 1):

buf[i] (or *(buf + i)) is ith character in buf.

Answer (score 1):

You can address a string (char*) as an array of char:

```
 char x = buf[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but at first glance I'd say you just need to use array accessing:

```
char *bar(char *buf)
{
  char newFifthCharacter = 'X';
  buf[4] = newFifthCharacter;
  return buf;
}
```

Note that you need to have a way to do bounds-checking so you don't write beyond the end of the array. You can either use the `strlen` function in `bar`, or you can have an integer parameter containing the length. Passing the length is probably better practice.